# Sql Server - XML shredding where xmlns is defined

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, shred

I have problem shredding an XML file if xmlns is defined in a document as seen here:

```
DECLARE @XML XML 
SET @XML=N'
<Doc1 xmlns="http://www.sample.com/file" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sample.com/file/long/path.xsd">
    <header>
        <stuff>data</stuff>
        <morestuff>data</morestuff>
    </header>
 </Doc1>'
```

I use following code for shredding:

```
SELECT 
T.c.query('stuff').value('.', 'char(50)') AS stuff1,
T.c.query('morestuff').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS morestuff
FROM @XML.nodes('Doc1/header') AS T(c);
```

Which of course would not work. Although if I remove

```
xmlns="http://www.sample.com/file" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sample.com/file/long/path.xsd"
```

so I will end up only with <'Doc1> the select statement works fine? I know it has something to do with namespaces but I simply cannot find a solution to this problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Doc1` and its sub elements are in the namespace `http://www.sample.com/file`. Use [`WITH XMLNAMESPACES`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx) to align the query with this namespace:

```
DECLARE @XML XML;
SET @XML=N'
<Doc1 xmlns="http://www.sample.com/file" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance"   
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sample.com/file/long/path.xsd">
    <header>
        <stuff>data</stuff>
        <morestuff>data</morestuff>
    </header>
 </Doc1>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.sample.com/file' as x)
SELECT 
T.c.query('x:stuff').value('.', 'char(50)') AS stuff1,
T.c.query('x:morestuff').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS morestuff
FROM @XML.nodes('x:Doc1/x:header') AS T(c);
```

[SqlFiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/33721)